# How to add a functionality to onchange_product_id method in sale.order.line in Odoo 8?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

I want to extend the onchange_product_id method of the sale.order.line model. I tried to do it in new and old api style, but nothing worked. Here are my tries:

Old api:

```
import logging
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class sale_order_line(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

    def onchange_product_id(self, cr, uid, ids, product_id, context=None):
        _logger.debug('product_id has changed')
        return {}
```

New api:

```
from openerp import models, fields, api
import logging

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class sale_order_line(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

    @api.onchange('product_id')
    def onchange_product_id(self):
        _logger.debug('product_id has changed')
        return True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way (I didn't try it yet, but it should work)

```python
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class CustomSaleOrderLine(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

    def product_id_change(self, cr, uid, ids, pricelist, product, qty=0,
            uom=False, qty_uos=0, uos=False, name='', partner_id=False,
            lang=False, update_tax=True, date_order=False, packaging=False, fiscal_position=False, flag=False, context=None):

        # some operations

        return super(CustomSaleOrderLine, self).product_id_change(cr, uid, ids, pricelist, product, qty,
            uom, qty_uos, uos, name, partner_id,
            lang, update_tax, date_order, packaging, fiscal_position, flag, context)
```

Comment: man, your genius! thanks! It should say `return super(CustomSaleOrderLine, self).product_id_change ...` but then it works perfectly!
There is no way you can do it in odoo8, is there?

Comment: AAh yes, sorry, I changed it in the last second. I will update the answer. You are welcome!!

Comment: I didn't find a way to do it with the Odoo 8 api, sorry. Maybe you have to override the method in a similar way and then you can use de `@api.onchange` operator